# xcodebuild archive keeps trying to use "Development Certificate" even if I specify an "AdHoc Distribution" provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, adhoc, apple-developer

I have been trying to build iOS app from command line (on Mac Machine) using xcodebuild command.

Here's the command I am using to export the archive:

```
xcodebuild -project "Path/BuildOutput/XCode/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj" -scheme "Unity-iPhone" archive -archivePath "Path/BuildOutput/XCode/Archive.xcarchive" -destination "generic/platform=iOS" -configuration Release PROVISIONING_PROFILE="xxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy"
```

The profile "xxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy" is created on my Apple Developer website as an "Ad Hoc" type profile, and it uses a certificate with type "Distribution", which in creation is displayed as "Apple Distribution"

I am getting the following error:

```
error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXXXXXXX" with a private key was found. (in target 'Unity-iPhone' from project 'Unity-iPhone')
```

The error does not occur when I am using a provisioning profile with type "Development" and the corresponding certificate is also "iOS Development" type. It seems that despite I specify a profile with "Ad Hoc" type, xcodebuild still tries to find a corresponding "iOS Development" type certificate while the actual certificate type does not match.

The "Apple Distribution" certificate shows up correctly when I go to XCode Preference and "Manage Certificate"

I am stuck at this point and don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this same issue with Xcode 13. Xcode seems to be mixing up profiles/certs.

In the IDE, I noticed that I could fix this issue by re-selecting the provisioning profiles for each configuration (dev/QA/prod in my case). I had to select the wrong profile for each configuration, then the correct one, and I would see the error disappear. xcodebuild worked.

To fix without messing with Xcode, I added the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution" option to xcodebuild

In your case:

```
xcodebuild -project "Path/BuildOutput/XCode/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj" -scheme "Unity-iPhone" archive -archivePath "Path/BuildOutput/XCode/Archive.xcarchive" -destination "generic/platform=iOS" -configuration Release PROVISIONING_PROFILE="xxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution"
```